# Close modal A after opening modal B from modal A in reactjs with react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The case is like I have a registration button and when I am clicking on that then signup modal will popup. Now I want to open Login modal from signup modal but signup modal should be closed after login modal popped up.

```
show={this.props.signupModalOn}
onHide={this.props.onSignupModalCall}
```

```
show={this.props.loginModalOn}
onHide={this.props.onLoginModalCall}
```

Here is [the code](https://codeshare.io/2KVnw8) for ModalA.js and ModalB.js

I tried some cases and I am getting nested popup modal but the first modal is not getting closed.

Comment: Can you please post the full component? The best bet is to connect the opening call of Modal B with a closing call of Modal A.

Comment: @Gh05d you mean something like this `onClick={ this.onLoginModalCall && this.offSignupModal}`

Comment: No this is just a check which will return true or false. You have to call both functions. So it should be in the onClick of Modal B.

Comment: @Gh05d I have provided the full component.

Comment: @Gh05d [Code is here](https://codeshare.io/2KVnw8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Sign-Up modal is handled by the parent of the component you have to pass down the `setState` function to be able to update it in the child component. Let's call the function `parentStateUpdate` and the state value `signUpModalOn` for simplicity:

```
<ModalA parentStateUpdate={value => this.setState({ signUpModalOn: value })} />;
```

Then you can modify `onLoginModalCall` like this:

```
onLoginModalCall = () => {
  this.setState({ loginModalOn: !this.state.loginModalOn, static: true });
  parentStateUpdate({ signUpModalOn: false });
};
```

Comment: Whatever I get  I have updated the code.. but it's not working for me. Am I doing something wrong? [code is here](https://codeshare.io/2KVnw8) line no 35

Comment: Try it with `this.props.parentStateUpdate`.

Comment: Have you passed the update function to the right component? Can you share a minimal reproducible example somewhere (like on codepen)?